# how to break uilabel line in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I really can't figure it out how to break line at ui label when it reach it max width.It keep showing me "xxxxx....".So,is there any other way that I can do line break at uilabel in swift?I am sure that the data string that i fetch from json will be more longer than like this.So,any idea?

I already set numberOfLines to zero which still didn't work out.

[image: enter link description here]

Actually the text is "(2010) Toyota Corolla Fielder has won from our system!!!"

Comment: Are you using auto layouts

Comment: use sizeTofit with label!

Comment: Have you added the label yourself or is it the default `titleLabel` avaiable in `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: @Losiowaty,I have created this label outlet by creating xxxTableCell.swift and join to my storyboard label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the previous answer was removed, but I managed to grab the screenshot of your constraints for the label :

[image]

We can see from it that your label has constraint on its height made by its top and bottom constraints. It simply cannot grow vertically without breaking any of this constraints. To resolve your issue I'd suggest changing the `Bottom Space to:` constraint to be a `Less than or equal` constraint. To do this double click on the constraint in the inspector, and change the `Relation` in the menu.

Comment: ok can you please help me for my next question?Its about tableview cell length grow higher base on label length.I will share the link soon

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891244/how-to-set-tablecell-row-height-automatically-based-on-inner-view-outlet